# Overlap parent div without css position attribute

Tags: html, css

There is a major problem i cannot solve which is related to the following problematic.

I have one div `.content` where all my content goes and is formatted by this very first div. The content could e.g. also be another div, a table or plain text. 
However, i also want to allow the style `.breaking-content` which can overriding style properties of the parent div `.content`. By default the breaking content should be in the flow of the document.

In this case i want especially inner `.breaking-content` divs to be able to overlap the parent div `.content`. This can be achieved with CSS via `position: absolute;`. But i get another problem as result as the `.breaking-content` is no more in the flow of the document as it overlaps `.breaking-content + *` - because of the absolute positioning.

```css
html, head, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p.textual {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.main-content {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #886632;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.content {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FF8632;
}

.breaking-content {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #44F632;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.breaking-content + * {
    /*Select first element after breaking content*/
    background-color: #5518F9
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
        <div class="content">
            <p class="textual">Bacon ipsum dolor amet jowl short loin sausage beef ribs fatback pastrami t-bone hamburger turducken meatloaf frankfurter strip steak.</p>
            <div class="breaking-content">Alcatra flank hamburger tenderloin frankfurter bresaola t-bone ground round boudin pig short loin kielbasa bacon beef.</div>
            <p class="textual">Boudin meatloaf short ribs alcatra andouille tail drumstick tongue porchetta hamburger shoulder shank beef.</p>
            <p class="textual">Bacon ipsum dolor amet jowl short loin sausage beef ribs fatback pastrami t-bone hamburger turducken meatloaf frankfurter strip steak.</p>
            <div class="breaking-content">Alcatra flank hamburger tenderloin frankfurter bresaola t-bone ground round boudin pig short loin kielbasa bacon beef.
        </div>
            <span class="textual">Prosciutto leberkas sausage picanha, meatball flank chicken t-bone frankfurter.</span>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/29fdocqo/1/

I'd like to solve this problem without javascript but if it is not possible i'd use it anyway.

Comment: Do you mean you want `.breaking-content` to be within the document flow, but have different styling? Or do you want `.breaking-content` to be above the flow, as you have it now? Just trying to understand what is your problem.

Comment: Sorry, it is supposed to be within the document flow. You might notice those purple/blue boxes which are overlapped by a green div. I want those blue ones to be fully visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see why you don't just close up `.content`. And then restart it after as such.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29fdocqo/2/)

UPDATE:

Sorry i went back and found you another solution.

```
.breaking-content {
    width: 200%;
    background-color: #44F632;
    margin-left: -50%;
}
```

[Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29fdocqo/3/)

Comment: This is indeed a solution to the problem i haven't thought about yet. But it won't solve the problem as a whole though. I might not be able to close the div in my case - without Javascript. I will try to fix my problem based on this and report back.

Comment: I have added a new answer.

Comment: Ok i very much like this answer, because it is a pure CSS solution. Big thumbs up for that. No more bad dreams about it :)